# databinding in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a xaml with a button like this:

Button.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <StackPanel >
           <Button Content="Button1" Click="Button1_Click" />
    </StackPanel >
 </Grid>
```

and Button.xaml.cs:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a instance of ClientOversikt
        CustomerView childWindow = m_container.Resolve<CustomerView >();
        childWindow.Show();
    }
```

It's working fine. But I want to use Databinding in Button.xaml instead of Click="Button1_Click". How could I do it?

I appreciate all the help

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using Silverlight 4, you can use [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  You bind the `Command` property of the `Button` to an instance of `ICommand`, which will open the child window when executed.  Then, when you click on the button, the command will be executed.

[This page](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-4-How-to-Command-Control.aspx) contains a reasonably good introduction to commanding.

Comment: @tle: There's code in the second link above.  Is this not sufficient?